# Connecting to Dynamics CRM database hosted in the "cloud" on Office 365

Tags: sql-server, django, database, crm

The company I work for uses Microsoft Dynamics CRM to track our clients and is hosted through Office 365. It has the most up-to-date client information.

Up until now we have been maintaining a second database with duplicate data that is used for the internal database... as you might have guessed it doesn't get updated with the latest information, so we run into issues where a query is run and pulls out of date client information.

Instead of queries using the internal database's client list, I want to pull the data from the CRM database. Has anyone done this before and have experience with it? Not finding much on it. The URL is something like `https://businessname.crm.dynamics.com`. Oh and I am using Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the database for CRM online. However CRM has a number of web services which provide easy access to data, you will probably want to use the Web API.

There is a lot of documentation available on the MSDN; [Use Microsoft Dynamics 365 web services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt608128.aspx).